# como generar con javascript un id a un td dentro de un bucle for

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, table, id

tengo esta tabla que se genera con javascript, para lo que necesito hacer, es necesario generar un id con los valores de i y de j. Me pueden ayudar por favor?

document.write("")

```
for(i=0;i<8;i++){

     document.write("<tr></tr>")   

        for(j=0;j<8;j++){
            if(i%2==0 && j%2==0){
                document.write("<td width='100px' height='110px' bgColor='white'></td>")


            }else if(i%2!=0 && j%2!=0){
                document.write("<td width='100px' height='110px' bgColor='white'></td>")
            } else if (i%2==0 && j%2!=0) {
                document.write("<td  width='100px' height='110px' bgColor='black'></td>")
            } else if (i%2!=0 && j%2==0){
                document.write("<td  width='100px' height='110px' bgColor='black'></td>")
            }

        }



}
```

document.write("")

Answer (score 0):

Si te entendí bien es colocar un `id` a cada etiqueta `<td>` que contega la variable `ì` y `j` de los dos bucles que estas realizando

```js
for(i=0;i<8;i++){
    document.write("<tr></tr>")   
    for(j=0;j<8;j++){
        var idTd= "td-"+i+j;
        if(i%2==0 && j%2==0){
            document.write("<td id='"+idTd+"' width='100px' height='110px' bgColor='white'></td>");
        }else if(i%2!=0 && j%2!=0){
            document.write("<td id='"+idTd+"' width='100px' height='110px' bgColor='white'></td>");
        } else if (i%2==0 && j%2!=0) {
            document.write("<td id='"+idTd+"' width='100px' height='110px' bgColor='black'></td>");
        } else if (i%2!=0 && j%2==0){
            document.write("<td id='"+idTd+"' width='100px' height='110px' bgColor='black'></td>");
        }
    }
}
```